# Regex to remove parentheses containing figure or table references

Tags: regex

I want to remove the parentheses from strings containing table or figure references. The parentheses can include multiple references. The pattern is somewhat consequent. Here are some examples:

```
text = [
"this is a figure ref (figure 7\xe2\x80\x9377)",
"this is multiple refs (figures 6\xe2\x80\x9328 and 6\xe2\x80\x9329)",
"this is a table ref (table 6\xe2\x80\x931)"
]
```

I'm using the following regex:

```
text = re.sub(r"\(([\w]\s\d(\\[a-z]+[0-9])+)\)", " ", text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove any parentheses that start with `table` or `figure`:

```py
re.sub(r'\s*\(\s*(?:table|figure)[^()]*\)', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iF7XWu/1). *Details*:

- `\s*\(\s*` - `(` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces on both ends
- `(?:table|figure)` - `table` or `figure` string
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NcAwx5):

```py
import re
text = [
"this is a figure ref (figure 7\xe2\x80\x9377)",
"this is multiple refs (figures 6\xe2\x80\x9328 and 6\xe2\x80\x9329)",
"this is a table ref (table 6\xe2\x80\x931)"
]
text = [re.sub(r'\s*\(\s*(?:table|figure)[^()]*\)', '', t) for t in text]
print(text)
# => ['this is a figure ref', 'this is multiple refs', 'this is a table ref']
```